# How to update array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update an array that is in Mongodb using mongoose on NodeJS.

[1] I get an array by restAPI as req.body.

```
 const workInform = req.body;

 console.log(workInform) 

 // [
      {name: 'hi',
       x: 120,
       y: 130,
       image: 'abc'
      },
       {name: 'bye',
       x: 20,
       y:10,
       image: 'ee'
      }
    ]
```

[2] There is a data for workInform in mongodb.

```
 { _id: '1234',
   works: [
   {name: 'hi',
    x: 120,
    y:130,
    image: 'abc'
   },
   {name: 'bye',
    x: 110,
    y:120,
    image: 'ee'
   }
  ]
 }
```

[3] workInform gets two array file like name 'hi' and 'bye'. 
    But 'bye' is only updated. So I want to update automatically only the data changed, even though I put every array data.

    ps) only x, y are changed not all data. e.g) image value is same.
    First, finding depends on 'userID' by using query.
    Second, pushing workInform using $push query of mongoose.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { uid: req.query.id },
      { $push: { works: workInform } },
      {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
      },
    );
```

But the update isn't executed well. Could you give me some advice? Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: when you say update isn't executed well, does it mean data was not updated? or data was updated but 2 new entries made? A new collection was made? worth sharing the outcome.

Comment: Nothing is changed..

Comment: one of the reason could be you don't have any key named 'uid' in your collection. Unless you have posted only few keys from your document.